# wagtail AbstractImage, ParentalManyToManyField and ClusterableModel

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail

Using wagtail 2.1, django 2.0.3, python 3.6.4

I have the following (simplified) custom image model, linked to `PhotoType` and `PhotoPlate` via m2m relationships:

```
from wagtail.images.models import AbstractImage
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalManyToManyField
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

class PhotoType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Title', max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, default=None)

class PhotoPlate(models.Model):
    plate= models.CharField(verbose_name='Title', max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, default=None)

class Photo(AbstractImage):
    type = ParentalManyToManyField(PhotoType, help_text="Several are allowed.", blank=True)
    plate = ParentalManyToManyField(PhotoPlate, help_text="Several are allowed.", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Photo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Photos'
```

The `PhotoType` and `PhotoPlate` models are referenced via `modeladmin_register(PhotoTypeModelAdmin)` and  `modeladmin_register(PhotoPlateModelAdmin)` in the local `wagtail_hooks.py` file.

All works fine after following the [documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/advanced_topics/images/custom_image_model.html).

Except for one thing: no matter how many items are selected in the multiple choice dropdowns that are rendered for the two fields `type` and `plate`, the corresponding m2m relationship is never saved.
I found a few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858703/wagtail-admin-checkboxselectmultiple-not-saving-data), but could get it to work by playing with the inheritance of the Photo class, for example: `class CCAPhoto(ClusterableModel, AbstractImage)`.

Is there any way to add a `ParentalManyToManyField` to a custom image model? If so, what am I missing?

EDIT:
When manually adding a relationship to the database, the right items are properly displayed on the wagtail admin form - -i.e., pre-selected on initial load.

Comment: Instead of using `ParentalManyToManyField`, does a standard `models.ManyToManyField` work?

Comment: @gasman I shall try this, hold on a sec :-)

Comment: @gasman yes it does! I would love an explanation about this -- and a real answer to accept, maybe? :) -- or I will just make one and accept it, up to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `ParentalManyToManyField`, you should use a plain `ManyToManyField` here:

```
class Photo(AbstractImage):
    type = models.ManyToManyField(PhotoType, help_text="Several are allowed.", blank=True)
    plate = models.ManyToManyField(PhotoPlate, help_text="Several are allowed.", blank=True)
```

The `ParentalManyToManyField` and `ParentalKey` field types are designed for use in Wagtail's page editor (and related areas such as snippets), where multiple models need to be treated together as a single unit for previewing and version tracking. Wagtail's image and document models don't make use of this - they consist of a single model edited through an ordinary Django ModelForm, so `ParentalManyToManyField` and `ParentalKey` aren't necessary.